# Converting object values into an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am trying to extract to the first five columns (only the data, not the keys) from an Object into an array.

For example, this is my Object:

```
(22) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Each individual element is composed of the following values:

```
change: 0
changeOverTime: 0
changePercent: 0
close: 0.92
date: "2020-05-13"
high: 1
label: "May 13"
low: 0.86
open: 0.99
uClose: 0.9161
uHigh: 1
uLow: 0.86
uOpen: 0.99
uVolume: 3471762
volume: 3471762
```

Now I want to create an 5x22 array that has the first five columns of the object. I.e The first row would be [0, 0, 0, 0.92, "2020-05-13"] and the I want the second Object array to fill the next row.

```
data = [ [0, 0, 0, 0.92, "2020-05-13"],
         [0, 0, 0, 0.95, "2020-05-14"], etc
       ]
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible that the keys are in different order in each object. So, it's better to get an array of the keys and map it so that you have the same property value in each *column*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get an array of values and [`array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get top `5`:

```js
let arr = [{change: 0,
changeOverTime: 0,
changePercent: 0,
close: 0.92,
date: "2020-05-13",
high: 1,
label: "May 13",
low: 0.86,
open: 0.99,
uClose: 0.9161,
uHigh: 1,
uLow: 0.86,
uOpen: 0.99,
uVolume: 3471762,
volume: 3471762}]

let result = arr.map(obj => Object.values(obj).slice(0,5));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: let result = arr.map(obj => Object.values(obj).slice(0,5)); This worked tysm!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:-

```js
let objectValue= [
{
   change: 0,
changeOverTime: 0,
changePercent: 0,
close: 0.92,
date: "2020-05-13",
high: 1,
label: "May 13",
low: 0.86,
open: 0.99,
uClose: 0.9161,
uHigh: 1,
uLow: 0.86,
uOpen: 0.99,
uVolume: 3471762,
volume: 3471762,
}];

console.log('Object to array:',Object.entries(objectValue));
```